# Gams and MATLAB intergration

Tags: matlab, path, ubuntu-14.04, configure, gams-math

I am trying to intergrate Gams and Matlab following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPn_q8nlktE)

The problem, however, is that MATLAB cannot see Gams using `system` command. More precise, I get an error:

```
/bin/bash: gams: command not found
```

My Gams installation folder is

```
/home/username/Gams/gams24.5_linux_x64_64_sfx
```

So, how can I say to MATLAB to run Gams from my home folder?

Comment: This is not a matlab question. You have to add the location of `gams` to your unix path. If you can run `gams` from the terminal as `gams`, then you can do the same from matlab. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) for instance.

Comment: i can run `gams` from terminal as `gams` without any problem. However, when I open matlab and run `system 'gams ? lo=3'` i get the above error

Comment: Are you running matlab from the same directory as where the call works in bash? Have you restarted matlab since installing gams? Have you tried `system('gams ? lo=3')`? `echo $PATH` in bash and `system('echo $PATH')` in matlab should give the same result. Do they?

Comment: matlab's running directory is `/usr/local/bin/matlab'. I have also set the path in matlab of my gams running directory, but either `system('gams ? lo=3')` command produces the above error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a `system` call will not look for the matlab path: it spawns a shell process, so the executable should be on your `$PATH`. That's why I asked: what do `echo $PATH` (in bash) and `system('echo $PATH')` (in matlab) return?

Comment: both two commands return `/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: The location of `gams`, which is `/home/username/Gams/gams24.5_linux_x64_64_sfx`, is not on your unix path, so you can't run it by just saying `gams`. Actually, it shouldn't work from the terminal either. Just to check: try `cd ~/Gams/gams24.5_linux_x64_64_sfx;` in matlab, then again try running `gams`. If it works: add the `gams` installation directory to your path, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: I tried to reinstall gams into my system's directory. Now `echo $PATH` sees gams (`/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/gams/gams24.5_linux_x64_64_sfx
`), but system('echo $PATH') does not (`/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
`)

Comment: Have you restarted matlab since the reinstall?

Comment: yes... but still matlab doesn't recognise it. I also added the new installation path into maltab, but nothing happened

Comment: I don't know what it's wrong... I guess I will give up! Thank you very much for your time and effort :) :) :)

Comment: Wait. The unix path is also shell-dependent. Start up a *new* shell, and start matlab from there. If that *also* doesn't help, I'll give up as well:)

Comment: ok... that's quite strange. I always started matlab from launcher. Now, I started from the terminal and now it recognizes gams. Everything seems to work perfectly. Probably it was that shell-dependence that you previously mentioned

Comment: You are a true life saver!!!! :) :) :)

Comment: No problem. I think if you restart the whole computer, everything should be OK. Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: (This question was solved in the comments: in the spirit of a comment in [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252565/low-quality-question-solved-in-the-comments-what-to-do), which fits because GAMS users are generally new to computing,  this is just a reformulation of what was discussed in the comments.

Since `system` command spawns a shell, the error is coming directly from the shell output. The error reads "`/bin/bash: gams: command not found`". Which is a clear indication that the `gams` binary is not recognized as a valid shell command. Most of the times, what happens is that the gams binary isn't registered in that shell `$PATH` variable.

The easiest way to solve this (if that is the problem) is to reinstall gams (it offers the option to add it to $PATH). More elegant ways involve [adding the binary to `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)